# Why does Skanda Purana say to cut off the tongue of a low-caste person who reads the Vedas?

Tags: scripture, shudra, skanda-purana, punishment, caste

In [Skanda Purana 5.3.200.6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc793805.html), there's a verse

> वेदोच्चारणमात्रेण क्षत्रियैर्धर्मपालकैः ।
> जिह्वाछेदोऽस्य कर्तव्यः शूद्रस्येति विनिश्चयः ॥ ६ ॥
>
> vedoccāraṇamātreṇa kṣatriyairdharmapālakaiḥ |
> jihvāchedo'sya kartavyaḥ śūdrasyeti viniścayaḥ || 6 ||
>
> It has been decided that for merely pronouncing the Veda [...] the tongue of that Śùdra should be cut off by Kṣatriyas who are the protectors of Dharma.

Why must this be done?

Comment: I think it's figurative. As the verses in purans are poetic. Same with Mahabharata and ramayan too. Like in Mahabharata, multiple people are said to possess strength of 10,000 elephants, so it doesn't literally mean that even tho they were incredibly strong. The verse here basically restricts shudras of listening to Vedic mantras.

Comment: Puranas are puranas, they are read for entertainment and inculcating bhakti, they aren't meant for serious level of hinduism. The laws and ideas defined there are just poetic.

Comment: This is my understanding of the scriptures, Sorry I cannot provide sources for how I have understood scriptures, just like like one cannot provide sources for their thoughts https://rockmine.blogspot.com/2023/10/stackexchange-why-does-skanda-purana.html

Answer (score 1):

One explanation offered by Medhatithi is that whoever studies the Vedas should study the whole thing, not just a few verses/passages from here and there. Therefore a shudra is to be punished for pronouncing a single sentence from the Veda.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145579.html

> We now proceed to explain the etymology of the word ‘Veda.’ The ‘Veda’ is that from which people derive their knowledge of Dharma, which cannot be known from any other source of knowledge—[ vidanti asmāṭ iti vedaḥ ]; and this knowledge of Dharma is derived from each individual sentence; hence the name is not restricted to the entire collection of Adhyāyas and Anuvākas that go under the name ‘Ṛgveda.’ **It is on this understanding that the penalty of having the tongue cut off is inflicted (upon the Śūdra) when he pronounces a single sentence out of the Veda. On the same principle also is the epithet ‘whole’ found in the injunction that ‘the whole Veda should be studied,’ where it serves to indicate the necessity of studying all the sentences contained in the Veda**; otherwise (if the epithet ‘whole’ were not there) the learner would be satisfied with the reading of only a few sentences, and would not read the whole Veda. All this we shall explain in detail in the present work.

But by this reasoning, even a brahmana or kshatriya should receive the same punishment for abandoning their Vedic studies but afaik no harsh punishment is prescribed for them.

Not sure if you're looking for a historical explanation. In case you are, here's one:

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.24397/page/n212/mode/1up

> The study of the Veda follows after Upanayana and the Veda speaks of the Upanayana of only three classes. One should perform upanayana for a brahmana in spring, for a rajanya in summer and in sarad ( autumn ) for a vaisya. Not only was the sudra not to study the Veda, but Veda study was not to be carried on in his presence. This attitude need not cause wonder. **The sacred Vedic literature was largely created and preserved entirely by the brahmanas ( the kshatriyas contributing if at all a very small share in that task ). If the brahmanas desired to keep their sacred treasure for the twiceborn classes in these circumstances**, it is understandable and for those ages even excusable.

Comment: Another question. Why so harsh punishment just for this mistake?

Comment: It's harsh to prevent Shudras from learning Vedas. I don't think the punishment is actually carried out.

Answer (score 0):

Because brahma has created natya shastra as an alternative for shudras as per [natyashastra ch.1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-natyashastra/d/doc202329.html) :

> *7-12. “Get yourselves cleansed, be attentive and hear about the origin of the Nāṭyaveda devised by Brahmā. O Brahmins, in the days of
> yore when the Golden Age (Kṛtayuga) passed with the reign of
> Svāyambhuva [Manu], and the Silver Age (Tretāyuga) commenced with the
> career of Vaivasvata Manu, and people became addicted to sensual
> pleasures, were under the sway of desire and greed, became affected
> with jealousy and anger and [thus] found their happiness mixed with
> sorrow, and Jambudvīpā protected by the Lokapālas (guardians of the
> worlds) was full of gods, Dānavas, Gandharvas, Yakṣas, Rākṣasas and
> great Uragas (Nāgas), the gods with the great Indra as their head,
> [approached] Brahmā and spoke to him, “We want an object diversion,
> which must be audible as well as visible. **As the [existing] of Vedas
> are not to be listened to by those born as Śūdras, be pleased to
> create another Veda which will belong [equally] to all the
> Colour-groups (varṇa)**.”*
>
> *13. “Let it be so,” said he in reply and then having dismissed the king of gods (Indra) he resorted to yoga and recalled to mind the four
> Vedas.*
>
> *14-15. He then thought: “I shall make a fifth Veda on the **Nāṭya** with the Semi-historical Tales (itihāsa), which will **conduce to duty**
> **(dharma), wealth (artha) as well as fame, will contain good counsel**
> **and collection [of traditional maxims]**, **will give guidance to people**
> **of the future as well, in all their actions, will be enriched by the**
> **teaching of all authoritative works (śāstra) and will give a review of**
> **all arts and crafts.**”*